# What is the default location for MSBuild logs?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012. Where is the location of the log file? I have searched in the folder where my solution and projects are stored, but cannot find any .log file.

This is the configuration for logging:

[image]

Comment: There is no default .log file.  Look in the Output window.

Comment: @Hans, In my case, the output window has messages saying "more information is available in the build log." so there is a separate log somewhere. I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Log file from Visual Studio is only supported for C++ projects.** You just have to work with **the output window for others.**

See this similar thread: [VS2010: minimal build log in output and detailed log in log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422428/vs2010-minimal-build-log-in-output-and-detailed-log-in-log-file)

And in case you happen to do this for a C++ project, [the file is at](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0bktkzs.aspx):

> ... build log in the intermediate files directory 
>   ... The path and name of the build log is represented by the MSBuild macro 
>   expression, `$(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log`.

Comment: I think that's just silly of Visual Studio not to have detailed logging in a file. Oh well, a reality I have to accept. Thanks for your answer, @Dmitry

Comment: @hanxue - It does have a log. That log is just not sent to a file. If you want a log file, run msbuild from the command line.

Comment: THEN WHY DOESN'T IT SAY SO :-(

Comment: God. Damnit. Why isnt this just a property on the solution? Why is the output window so terrible performance anyway so you are forced to keep it on minimal output all the time, and why is it like 8 steps to change from one output level to the other? Fix any of these please.

Comment: @James I guess you could be able to write a macro and assign it to the toolbar button. These links could be a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015 and https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 `IntDir` means intermediate directory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019

Comment: not the answer I'm looking for. but yeah. that's how MS works

Answer (score 34):

Use build output instead of logging to file. Instead of copy/paste, simply click somewhere in the output and press CTRL + S to save. Visual Studio will prompt you for a location (tested with Visual Studio 2017, but I'm assuming this works in earlier versions too).

[image]

Comment: This is good. They should put this in the context menu as well.

Comment: not useful for me because the logs in output doesn't have the complete log output

Comment: @ajgo build output level of details is configurable in MSBuild build project output verbosity as show in the screenshot in the original question

Comment: I tried that to set it to verbose and the full detail was just truncated which I have said before. it doesn't have the complete log output

Answer (score 24):

The msdn documentation is pretty clear about this (And you ain't gonna like it!):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx

Where it says:

> To create a build log file for a managed-code project On the menu bar,
>   choose Build, Build Solution.
>
> In the Output window, highlight the
>   information from the build, and then copy it to the Clipboard.
>
> Open a
>   text editor, such as Notepad, paste the information into the file, and
>   then save it.

Comment: Which is all well and good until you're using diagnostic output and VS decides to throw an 'out of memory' exception when you try to copy to the clipboard. Really is a fundamentally stupid decision not to support sending the build log to a file in the IDE. But hey ho, such is life.

Comment: Pipe the build into a text file? msbuild mysln.sln >output.txt (will probably need to add parameters to that to get your sln to compile, but you should be able to snag that from vs output window iirc at the correct verbosity level)

Comment: Usually when I build on the command line, I make my build systems output minimal information to the terminal window, but a detailed log to a file. MSBuild can do that.

Comment: "And you ain't gonna like it!" That tells everything in 6 words, thanks

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that VS doesn't allow this directly, it is still possible to build with MSBuild "inside" VS2015 and get both the build window output and the log file, as follows: (Arguably this is a bit of a hack.)

1. In your VS Managed solution, add a new project (Let's call it 'Make').
   a. The project type you want is Visual C++/NMake project.
2. Define the MSBuild commands you need on the command line (see below).
3. Change the solution configuration to build the NMake project instead of the normal managed projects.

This will create a project that has Build, Rebuild, and Clean command lines where you can execute MSBuild directly.  For example:

Rebuild: `MSBuild.exe /ds /v:diag /property:Configuration=Debug ..\BuildTest\BuildTest.csproj /t:Clean,Build`

Build: `MSBuild.exe /ds /v:diag /property:Configuration=Debug ..\BuildTest\BuildTest.csproj /t:Build`

Clean: `MSBuild.exe /ds /v:diag /property:Configuration=Debug ..\BuildTest\BuildTest.csproj /t:Clean`

You can also specify multiple MSBuild.EXE command lines in order to build multiple projects.  For the usual build-the-entire-solution outcome you can target only the final end assemblies and let the dependency graph generate the individual targets.

This will produce a .log file, where NAME is the name of the NMake project you used.  In the example above, the log would be make.log.

A working example is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/bitblitz/VS_MsbuildExample
(Tested with VS2015)

Note that building individual projects directly will still build with the normal VS behavior, but you can build the full solution inside VS and get the build logs.

Comment: The link to VS_MsbuildExample is broken.

Comment: Hey @brad what happened to your example on GitHub?

Comment: Fixed github, sorry for trouble. @YannDuran