# Visual Studio MSBuild output log file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Where is the log file located? I'm doing a build and I can't find where that file is. Everything online says it's $IntDir, but it looks like it's only for CPP projects, not .NET. This is Visual Studio 2017 on a regular .NET console project. I can't locate the file anywhere. If I choose to do "detailed" in the output, it's far too large. I'd like to get detailed info in the log file only.

[image: VS Option]

I know you can do things via msbuild directly, but I'm trying to figure out what Visual Studio is doing that's different from what I'm doing via MSBuild directly so I can replicate what VS is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [there is no log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11529392/2137382) for managed projects - you can [save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505040/2137382) from the output pane.

You may also be interested in using the [MSBuild Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/), which has a VS plugin that lets you save binary-format MSBuild logs from Visual Studio, then open them in the viewer.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for confirming. Unfortunately it's not practical to do that. I'll try the log viewer. Thanks!