# Where are the build logs for an azure app service?

Tags: azure, logging, build, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

`D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.`

Now, I know what to do if this error message had come from Visual Studio: [Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772053/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembly-that-c)

The problem is that this error message comes from drilling into "Logs" in the Deployment Centre of my Azure web app (from clicking "Show Logs..." next to "Running deployment command..." I can't figure out where these reference conflicts are listed for an Azure app service despite trying to turn on as much logging as possible and searching for a solution to this problem.

Could someone please show me where to go to see where these conflicts are listed in an Azure app service? Where is the build log? How do I turn it "on"?

EDIT: I just found this: [What is the default location for MSBuild logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526552/what-is-the-default-location-for-msbuild-logs). I don't know if it applies to Azure.

**Update:**

The code is being continuously pulled into my Azure app from my Azure DevOps repository whenever I push a new code change. It's building (which includes compiling) on the server, somewhere. I just don't think there's any way to actually see the build logs. In Visual Studio, all we have is the output window, and there's no equivalent on the server.

Comment: Have you deployed to Azure?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Yes, a successful deployment.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Before viewing logs on Azure, be aware that `azure-web-sites` do not provide compilation capabilities, so compilation-related warnings and errors are not displayed in the logs. Azure's log feature is used to track runtime warnings or run-time errors, not compile-time.

---

Since you have deployed to Azure, please have a look of this:

Log stream:

[image]

From your description, you need to change the assembly which is mismatch with others.

If you still can't resolve this problem, please add the error and the assembly you used in your app service to this question text.

Comment: Thank you, but the Log Stream output doesn't contain anything like the error in my question (I'm looking at Web Server logs and Application logs and I've set it to Verbose and Filesystem in order to use the log streaming feature.) That error is literally the only detail the deployment centre gives you apart from the project it occurred in. I just need the Azure equivalent of getting this info in Visual Studio. And I've redeployed several times while streaming.

Comment: @nmit026 Or have a look of the files under `/LogFiles` on Kudu.

Comment: I have, the problem is that I can't find anything in Azure that's equivalent to what I can find with Visual Studio on my dev machine. I can't fix the conflicts mentioned because I don't know what they are. Where should I look exactly? Which file?

Comment: @nmit026 I have tried. It can't show on Azure Stream Log or Kudu because this is a compile-time warning. Please notice that Azure-Web-Site don't offer compiler, so this warning  will not show in the warning categorie of Application logging.

Comment: Thank you for trying! So this problem doesn't have a solution?

Comment: @nmit026 Yes, because you upload it to Azure after compiling, and azure-websites does not perform the compile operation. How does azure-web-site, which is not responsible for the compilation operation to display it? Azure's logging feature records runtime issues.Compile problems should be resolved at compile time (you can successfully deploy because you encounter warnings instead of errors. If you encounter compile-time errors, you cannot deploy your project, let alone watch it on Azure)

Comment: The code is being continuously pulled into my Azure app from my Azure DevOps repository whenever I push a new code change. It's building (which includes compiling) on the server, somewhere. I just don't think there's any way to actually see the build logs. In Visual Studio, all we have is the output window, and there's no equivalent on the server. Pretty poor design, but it is what it is. It seems there's no solution. We can only fix errors, not warnings.

Comment: @nmit026 I don't know Azure DevOps, Just now I've updated the answer and modified your question so that someone can solve your problem(still under review.). If it still doesn't, you can mark my answer as an answer to your question so that later people will not spend too much time on this.In summary, compilation issues cannot be viewed above azure-web-sites.

Comment: I still don't know that it can't be solved. For example, it may be possible to use powershell in Kudu to build and then pipe the output that normally goes to the output window in Visual Studio into a text file somewhere on the server. I just don't know if that's possible and don't want to mess anything up. If someone wants to try it and get back to me, that would be awesome. Thanks for your help. Also, I used the MSBuild tag before because that's what actually does the build, as you can see in the output in my question. Cheers