# Location log file Visual Studio 2019 project

Tags: visual-studio, logging, msbuild

My program thrown an exception that I don't understand and VS2019 show me this message:

```
Exception thrown while setting fields [IdPerm] in table [userperm] with value [893]. Check the logs for details'
```

I'm trying to find the log file but I can't do it. I read the following articles:

1- [What is the default location for MSBuild logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526552/what-is-the-default-location-for-msbuild-logs)

2- [Visual Studio log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809430/visual-studio-log-file)

3- [VS2010: minimal build log in output and detailed log in log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422428/vs2010-minimal-build-log-in-output-and-detailed-log-in-log-file)

so I added to my .csproj these instructions

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="notepad.exe $(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log" />
</Target>
```

but then when I execute on the command prompt `notepad.exe $(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log` I have another error: `Cannot find the path specified`

Comment: I don't understand, if it is your program that throws the exception, why are you looking for the Visual Studio log file?

Comment: @Steve because, as I wrote, VS shows me a message that says 'Check the logs for details'

Comment: Is it really VS which tells you that, or your program? Where is that message shown exactly? Does your program have a logfile?

Comment: “Cannot find the path specified“ indicates there is no $(MSBuildProjectName).log file generated. I think the message “Check the logs for details” that VS shown doesn’t mean MSBuild logs. Please check if the logs are shown in one displayed/prompt window/dialog of Visual Studio and share more information with us.